# add a notification message using before_footer hook in moodle

Tags: plugins, hook, moodle

```
function local_custom_message_before_footer() {
   //echo('hello');
   \core\notification::info('a test message'); }
```

i am trying to display a notification this way, i would like to display a message like "you need to retake the *(course name)* course in *(remaining days)* days".

Here,
*(course name)* is the course that we have used course recompletion feature, and
*(remaining days)* is how many days left to retake that course.

please suggest a way to continue further

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running a recent version of Moodle (3.10 or above) you need to return the content to output.

So, you'll need something like:

```
function local_custom_message_before_footer() { 
    global $OUTPUT;
    return $OUTPUT->notification('Example message', \core\output\notification::NOTIFY_WARNING, false);
}
```

If you're using Moodle 3.9 (or below), then you're out of luck - the '_before_footer' hook didn't support adding anything to the output in those versions (it only supported calling functions to add Javascript to the page).